# HTML5 canvas not redrawing in Chrome after calling clearRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been staring at this too long, and need some help.  I have the following simplified fiddle example that works in IE, but not in Chrome (no errors, just no images get redrawn after canvas is cleared in Chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/JrLh7/3/

```
var myApp = {};
// redraw function that will be called during init and then will loop.
myApp.redrawFunction = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(myApp.redrawFunction);
    // clear canvas (not needed in this simplified example, but I need it in my real app)
    myApp.drawingContext.clearRect(0, 0, myApp.canvas.width, myApp.canvas.height);
    // draw an image.
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.onload = function() {
        myApp.drawingContext.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
    };
    myImage.src= "http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/mark-word-icon.png";
};
// initialize
$(function () {
    // setup the animation frame objects.
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
        || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.CancelAnimationFrame
        || window.CancelRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame
        || window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.msCancelAnimationFrame
        || window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame
        || window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame;
    // get canvas references.
    myApp.canvas = $("canvas")[0];
    myApp.drawingContext = myApp.canvas.getContext("2d");
    $(myApp.canvas).css("background-color", "#999999");
    // update canvas size to fill screen.
    myApp.canvas.width = $(window).width();
    myApp.canvas.height = $(window).height();
    $(window).resize(function (){
        myApp.canvas.width = $(window).width();
        myApp.canvas.height = $(window).height();
    });
    // start redraw loop
    myApp.redrawFunction();
});
```

If you open this fiddle in IE 10, it works (you see a logo).  If you open this in Chrome, you see a blank canvas, showing that my drawImage call did not work after clearing the canvas.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're clearing the canvas, then you are waiting for an image to load, when the image loads, the animation runs again, clears the canvas and wait for the new image to load. Therefore, you always see the canvas state immediately after calling `clearRect`, because when you call `drawImage`, the animation routine will kick in again before you get a chance to see the result of `drawImage()` and you'll see the result of `clearRect()`.

The solution is not to clear the canvas until the image is ready to be painted. http://jsfiddle.net/JrLh7/6/

```
var myApp = {};
// redraw function that will be called during init and then will loop.
myApp.redrawFunction = function() {
    // Don't clear the canvas here, it will be empty until the onload handler is called 
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.onload = function() {
        // Clear canvas and immediately paint the image
        myApp.drawingContext.clearRect(0, 0, myApp.canvas.width, myApp.canvas.height);
        myApp.drawingContext.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
        // Then you should ask for another frame after you've finished painting the canvas
       window.requestAnimationFrame(myApp.redrawFunction);
    };
    myImage.src= "http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/mark-word-icon.png";
};
```

**Note**

It doesn't make a lot of sense to have an animation routine that is asynchronous. If so, at the very least, you shouldn't request a new animation frame until you've finished painting the canvas.

Comment: So the other strange thing is if I forget the clear part, and I animate the image instead, it keeps drawing the new image (and you will see a trail of the same image over and over).  This even works in Chrome if I keep creating new image objects.  I am just curious why clearing all of a sudden breaks it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xHMyN/1/ for example.  If creating multiple images is the issue, why wouldn't it fail to create the multiple images here?

Comment: @JeremyArmstrong I think I have the problem down, please check the answer

Comment: I need to rethink how I am queuing up my images before drawing them, but I think this is the answer I needed.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JeremyArmstrong Most games cache the images upfront, do you have so many that it's not feasible? I don't think the solution is to load them dynamically with every animation frame...

Comment: It is definitely feasible, I just didn't realize the issue completely until now.  I will work on preloading the images to get around this.