# Rotating Canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas

I have CustomClass with image at the center.

I use compass and rotate canvas.

When data from compass is changed the canvas is invalidate and redraw.

Have you any idea, to draw Canvas and rotate it without redraw?

My code is below:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);

    if (mValues != null) { 
       rotate=-mValues[0];
    }

    canvas.rotate(rotate); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgtable,  - imgtable.getWidth()/2, - imgtable.getHeight()/2, null);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below link it rectify your problem:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/Translation,Rotation,andScaling/Translation,Rotation,andScaling.html

(or)

below link already suggest in Stack Overflow Link below check it:

[HTML5 canvas not redrawing in Chrome after calling clearRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350969/html5-canvas-not-redrawing-in-chrome-after-calling-clearrect)